# is the Y-Combinator a monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lisp

I'm trying to understand the similarities between abstracting functions using the y-combinator and the continuation monad. Intuitively, it feels to me like they have things in common, but I haven't understood either of them to be able to grasp at an answer. Please help.

Comment: Combinators, continuations, and monads are all different kinds of thing, so it's hard to say what commonality you're looking for. Turning a directly recursive function into one that uses a fixed-point combinator does tend to require rewriting it in something like continuation-passing style, I suppose.

Comment: Monads in Haskell are data types of kind `* -> *` with some additional functions (`return` and `>>=`) satisfying some properties. On the other hand, a combinator is a closed term (a program with no free variables). So they are completely different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely different concepts. They only thing they have in common is that they are used to manage program control flow.